# Проблема с открытием JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x

Проблемный код:

```
 def check_mail(self, mail):
     f = open("base.json", 'r')
     text = f.read()
     result = json.loads(text)
     return result
```

И вывод:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Vadim/Documents/Python/Houme Task/reg.py", line 42, in <module>
    print(data.check_mail("sokle@gmail"))
  File "/Users/Vadim/Documents/Python/Houme Task/reg.py", line 32, in check_mail
    return json.loads(text)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 73 (char 72)
```

MacOS/CPython 3.5

Данные записываются в файл в таком формате:

```
{"sokle@gmail.com": ["Pavel", "nejcenwvewnvlewn"]}
```

Comment: Похоже что то с json-ом, можно его глянуть?

Comment: приведенный текст в примере соответствует тому, на  что указывает ошибка `...line 1 column 73 (char 72)`? Если это возможно, то приведите именно ту строку, на которую ругается `json.loads`

Comment: прогоните свой json в http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Валидацию проходит

Comment: приведённый json в вопросе никаких ошибок не выбрасывает. Приведите минимальный пример json, который ведёт к ошибке. Выбросьте одну половину файла, проверьте что ошибка осталась, если нет, то выбросите другую половину, проверьте что ошибка осталась итд, затем сохраните результат в invalid.json файл и покажите результат: `print(open("invalid.json", "rb").read())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Быть может причина в том, что Вы пытаетесь декодировать множественный `JSON`?
Работает:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('{}')
{}
```

Но:

```
>>> json.loads('{}{}')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    json.loads('{}{}')
  File "S:\Python\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "S:\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

Comment: Я пробовал открывать json  википедии к сожалению. Ошибка не изменна. проблема в кодировке, но как перекодировать я не знаю. Применял decode  к файлу при открытии , не помогает.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего дело в кодировке файла. Читаются лишние символы или невидимые символы ([похожие на UTF-8 BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2))

Вот что удалось поймать, при работе с строкой перед:

```
>>> result = json.loads(text)    
'п»ї{"sokle@gmail.com": ["Pavel", "nejcenwvewnvlewn"]}'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python35\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python35\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

И строкой после:

```
>>> text '{"sokle@gmail.com": ["Pavel", "nejcenwvewnvlewn"]}vdsv'
>>> result = json.loads(text) Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>   File
"C:\Python35\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
   return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "C:\Python35\lib\json\decoder.py", line 342, in decode
   raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end) json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 51 (char 50)
```

Отсюда, похоже на сторонние символы в данных, которых может быть не видно в "блокноте" или notepad++.

Далее, встаёт вопрос отсечения этих невидимых символов. Вероятнее всего, необходимо либо парсить регуляркой всё между первым "{" и последним "}", либо получать корректный ответ от того, кто его отправляет.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте лучше решение:

```
import json

with open("base.json") as json_file:
     json_data = json.load(json_file)
     print(json_data)
```

Answer (score -3):

Проблема была в том что я дописывал в json второй словарь, из-за этого не Открывало. Проблема решилась когда создал список и в него начал добавлять словари с данными. Всем спасибо за труды!

Comment: Т.е. по сути правильным ответом является ответ Other (у вас был множественный json).